# Почему слово "конференц-зал" пишется через дефис?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, раздельно-дефис

На одном учебном сайте написано: все сложносокращенные слова пишутся слитно.

Это так?

Слово  конференц-зал (зал **для** конференций)  очень похоже на сложносокращенное, но пишется через дефис. (Сравнить: вещмешок – мешок **для** вещей).

Может быть, это не сложносокращенное слово, а какое тогда?

Может быть, это исключение, но почему его "исключили"?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, это связано с невозможностью перехода слова "конференция" в согласованное определение. Можете привести ещё примеры таких слов? Моя фантазия что-то не работает.

Comment: Подсказка зала? Яхт-клуб, например.

Comment: Подтверждает мою теорию. Нет такого слова, как "яхтовый", насколько я знаю.

Comment: Хотя то же самое сочетание "компакт-диск" её рушит... По-моему, Александр всё верно сказал.

Comment: Можно сказать: клуб владельцев яхт и других  судов. Или (по словарю): Организация, объединяющая спортсменов водных видов спорта (парусного, гребного, моторного).

Comment: Это да. Но я заострял внимание именно на согласованных определениях.

Comment: На сайте Словари.ру вы можете найти больше информации по этому вопросу.К сожалению, ссылку пока не могу дать. С т/ф не копируется почему-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словах конференц-зал, аудиенц-зал первая основа является усеченной (ср. аудиенци-я, конференци-я, конференционный), но эти слова не принято относить к сложносокращенным. Исторически это объясняется тем, что они появились в результате заимствования, а не образовались в русском языке. Однако на синхронном уровне это является формальным ограничением определения. Также не считают сложносокращенными все слова с первой основой слов на -ия, -ий, -ие и соединительной гласной, в которых гласная и усечена, напр.: анархо-синдикалист (анархия), монархофашист (монархия).

Источник: Словари.ру.

Answer (score 3):

В таком порядке оказались слова при заимствовании словосочетания *conference hall*, которое из-за отсутствия русского окончания у первого слова понадобилось объединить в одно слово - здесь не было *сокращения* усечением. Похожий случай: "компакт-диск" (compact disc); здесь и вовсе выходило прилагательное без русского окончания.

Comment: Написание слова не связано со способом  его образования напрямую, здесь нужны правила русской орфографии, на которые можно сослаться. И грамматическую категорию слова нужно определить (сложное, сложносокращенное или другое)..

Comment: Интересно. Никогда не пробовал мыслить в пределах языков и заимствований.

Comment: Думаете, надо поставить плюсик?

Comment: Думаю, что надо.